# using software to change iphone field of view to a wider angle

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is it possible to use software to change iphone field of view to a wider angle? I need the camera to be a little bit wider for an application I am considering making.

Comment: Yes it is possible but what u want ?Explain proper

Comment: I am not sure how I can explain it any better but I will try. 

I would like to use the iPhone camera to track an object but the field of view of the iphone is not wide enough for my needs. I need the camera angle to be 20% wider to be able to track the object.

Comment: Add your code here